# How to add multiple methods for one field in jQuery validate

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Can jQuery validate plugin pass multiple methods through one field?

for example, add two methods:

```
var num1 = 1;
    num2 = 10;
    range1 = 100;
    range2 = 250;
    value = $("#something_from_html")

$.validator.addMethod("method_one", function( value, element ) {
    if(value < num1 || value > num2)
        return false;
    return method_one(value, num1, num2);
}, I18N("wrong number"));


$.validator.addMethod("method_two", function( value, element ) {
    if( value < range1 || value > range2) 
        return false;
    return method_two(value, range1, range2);   
}, I18N("wrong range"));
```

and return different warning message to one field:

```
$("#form").each(function(index, el)  {
    $(el).validate({
        rules: {
            something_from_html: {
                required: true,
                method_one: true,
                method_two: true
            },
        },

    });
});
```

the HTML part:

```
<form id="form" name="form">    
    <input type="text" name="something_from_html" id="something_from_html">
</form>
```

When I add one method to rule, it works perfectly. But when I add both of method_one and method_two, it doesn't work. Anybody know how to fix it?

Comment: Calling `each()` on an id selector is a little redundant. You have only got one element with the id of `form` in your HTML, right?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yes!! only got one element.

Comment: element pass  <input type="text" name="something_from_html" id="something_from_html">  this to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is due to the logic in your additional methods; they need to return a boolean indicating the validity of the entered value.
 Currently they attempt to call a global method with their defined validator method name which doesn't exist.

You also need to use `parseInt()` to convert the text value entered in to the input to an integer so that it can be compared to your `num` and `range` values. Also, those variables should be declared within the validator methods to save any scoping problems.
 Try this:

```
$.validator.addMethod("method_one", function(value, element) {
    var num1 = 1, num2 = 10;
    value = parseInt(value, 10);
    return !(value < num1 || value > num2);
}, I18N("wrong number"));


$.validator.addMethod("method_two", function(value, element) {
    var range1 = 100, range2 = 250;
    value = parseInt(value, 10);
    return !(value < range1 || value > range2);
}, I18N("wrong range"));
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/4of0noxy/)